# How to change Apache FOP Xalan XSLT Processor?

Tags: java, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, apache-fop

I am using Apache FOP 1.1.I want to change current apache Xalan XSLT processor to other for supporting XSLT 2.0.
   Currently it is not supporting XSLT 2.0.
Please help me  how to solve this problem.
thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got my Answer.
TransformerFactory has a **plug-ability** layer. 
JAXP provides a common Java interface that allows flexibilty to add  various implementations of the supported standards XSLT processors.

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
```

This had look-up procedure to locate XSLT processors.AS we does not defined any,it will take available or default.

Now, I am adding SAXON XSLT processor . I have added it's **.jar file** in my project and just added

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance("net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl",null);
```

That's it. now it will use Saxon XSLT processor

Answer (score 2):

Another more flexible way is to start your application with a VM parameter like this `-Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl`
which determines which Factory implementation to create (i.e. default XSLT processor).

This way, you don't have to change a single line of your code itself.

This is fine, if you embed FOP in your code (as you apparently did). If you want to run *FOP as standalone distribution* from command line, however, you can

1. copy the required jar files with the XSLT processor (like e.g.
   Saxon.jar) to the `lib` directory of your distribution
   (`$LOCAL_FOP_HOME/lib` on Linux, `%LOCAL_FOP_HOME%lib` on Windows)
2. and add the paramater to the start script (`fop` on Linux, `fop.bat`
   on Windows) at the line where `org.apache.fop.cli.Main` is called.

Answer (score 0):

or just

```
TransformerFactory factory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
```