# How do i log to a .txt file while processing the contents of XML using XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, apache-fop

I am working with Apache FOP.
I am using XSLT to convert XML to PDF (which works fine).
I need to create a journal file (basically a .txt file).
The journal file should consist of values from tag values from XML while processing it in XSLT. i require this journal file for some reconciliation.
Example:

```
<Details>
 <Name>Pooja</Name>
 <Country>India</Country>
 <OtherInfo>ABC</OtherInfo>
</Details>
```

I would need the .txt contents as below:

```
Pooja,India,ABC
```

How do i achieve this?

Comment: If you really use XSLT 2.0 then you have `xsl:result-document` for e.g. `<xsl:template match="Details"><xsl:result-document href="journal.txt" method="text"><xsl:value-of select="*" separator=","/></xsl:result-document></xsl:template>`. Use modes if other parts of your XSLT (i.e. the ones creating XSL-FO) process the `Details` element as well.

Comment: Really depends upon which XSLT processor and which version that you are using (or can use).

Comment: i figured i am using XSLT 1.0 :( How do i upgrade to 2.0 ?

Comment: @Pooja If you're using an XSLT 1.0 processor, then why is your question tagged `xslt-2.0`?? As to how can you upgrade, it depends on your environment, of which you have told us nothing. Perhaps this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379070/how-to-change-apache-fop-xalan-xslt-processor

Comment: @michael.hor257k I upgraded to 2.0 using the steps provided in the link and it worked wonders :)

Comment: That's good. Note that if you picked a recent version of Saxon then you have support for XSLT 3.0.

Comment: Well i used jar version 8.7. I guess i can download the latest too. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways that you could generate the CSV output. If there is a chance those values could contain `,` then you might want to add some logic to escape or wrap with quotes. But for the simple case of joining those element values with `,` you could start with either of these:

**XSLT 2.0** (or greater) using [`xsl:value-of`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#value-of) with `@separator=","`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="Details">
        <xsl:value-of select="*" separator=","/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 2.0** (or greater) using [`fn:string-join()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-string-join):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="Details">
        <xsl:value-of select="string-join(*,',')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 1.0** using `xsl:for-each` and testing the `position()` to determine whether to emit the `,`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="Details">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am using XSLT 1.0. Where exactly is the file getting created? I understand the for each and the output method. But where exactly is the filename and file location ?

Comment: @Pooja It is not possible in XSLT 1.0 to generate both an XSL-FO and a .txt file in a single transformation. You will need to run the transformation twice, either using 2 different stylesheets, or a single stylesheet with a different parameter at a time.